# How to build relations to Multiple IDs separated by comma in Yii

Tags: php, mysql, database, relational-database, yii

I was creating a form. Certian fields of the form uses checkbox and may return multiple choices and I have to store all of those IDs to a single field separated by a comma or semicolon.

Now what I am looking to is how can I build a relation to that record in Yii Framework.
Usually we use

```
'groupName' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Lookup', 'group'),
'p_cpu' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Product', 'cpu'),
```

But how will I do it in the following manner

```
'p_additionalSoftwares' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Product', 'additionalSoftwares'),
```

When the additionalSoftwares contain something like 2,8

Comment: this is must-have solution? I think i would convert this structure to smth more flexible. Like every additional software to separate row in the `softwares` table. And when make relation to this table. m?

Comment: I think you need to clarify the question a bit and specify what tables you are talking about -- I'm not really sure your exact problem -- if the additionalSoftwares are in the Product table you don't need a relation, if they are in different one, use a relation with product_id to tie them together. I also agree with @briiC.lv that you would generally want to create lookup table(s) to store the individual values.

Answer (score 0):

As this is not a real BELONGS_TO relation with a foreign key you can not use Yii's built in functions.
You may write a custom relation for this case based on CBaseActiveRelation or CActiveRelation, but I have no experience in that, but this may be the cleanest solution.

Another option would be to overwrite the get handler for your attribute, like*

```
public function getP_additionalSoftwares(){
  //Use value from database in attributes and split into array with primary keys
  $pks = explode(",",$this->attributes['p_additionalSoftwares']);
  //Query database
  $models = $this->findByPks($pks);
  return $models;
}
```

In your view:

```
$model->p_additionalSoftwares
```

Should return an array of models, like a relation.

**Note:** This may impact performance, because you may get a large number of subrequests to the database, as the records are all lazy loaded.

**code untested*